# filter results in error

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Let's suppose we have a `table`, which has some `tr` `children`. The very first `tr` has `th` `children` and the other `tr` elements have `td` children. Let's suppose an event upon a row is triggered. The jquery object of the given `tr` is `rawRow`. `row` will hold all the useful `td` elements of `rawRow`. I want to exclude the very first td if and only if the corresponding th has no inner text. This is how I tried to do it:

```
    var row = rawRow.children("td");
    if (!rawRow.parent().children("tr:first").children("th:first").text()) {
        row = row.filter(":not:first");
    }
```

This, however, results in an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

inside jquery-2.1.4.min.js.

If I look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), I can see a similar usage:

```
$( "li" ).filter( ":even" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

What did I do wrong in my script? Or is it a jquery bug?

EDIT:

While waiting for answers, I have been reading and experimenting. This solution works:

```
        row = row.filter(function(index) {
            return !!index;
        });
```

but naturally, this is an alternative, which does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using :not as a filter or selector use parentheses.

The error you are getting is just due to the way jQuery parses out the selectors.

```
var row = rawRow.children("td");
if (!rawRow.parent().children("tr:first").children("th:first").text()) {
    row = row.filter(":not(:first)");
}
```

Comment: Very nice, answer, Sean, I will accept it soon. I am going to eat now. I have tried it and it works as expected!